# c# gdal error "System.ApplicationException:“D:\test.tiff, band 1: Unhandled version of GDALRasterIOExtraArg”

Tags: c#

Use GDAL Band.WriteRaster(int, int, int, int, short []), int, int, int, osgeo. GDAL. Rasterioextraarg) function resamples the original image, but runs with an error: "system. Applicationexception:" D: \ test.tiff, band 1: unhandled version of gdalrasterioextraarg "

```
 public Dataset NearestNeighbour(Dataset oriimg,Dataset srcimg)
    {
        OSGeo.GDAL.RasterIOExtraArg extraArg=new RasterIOExtraArg();
        extraArg.eResampleAlg =RIOResampleAlg.GRIORA_NearestNeighbour;
        //DataType dataType = oriimg.GetRasterBand(1).DataType;
        int bandsnum = oriimg.RasterCount;
        int orilines = oriimg.RasterYSize;
        int orisamples = oriimg.RasterXSize;
        int srclines = srcimg.RasterYSize;
        int srcsamples = srcimg.RasterXSize;
        int[] oribanddata = new int[orilines * orisamples];
        for(int i=1;i<=bandsnum;i++)
        {
            oriimg.GetRasterBand(i).ReadRaster(0, 0, orisamples, orilines, oribanddata, orisamples, orilines, 0, 0);
            srcimg.GetRasterBand(i).WriteRaster(0, 0, orisamples, orilines, oribanddata, srcsamples, srclines, 0, 0, extraArg);
        }
        return srcimg;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set

```
extraArg.nVersion = 1;
```